# Sharepoint search not indexing correctly with Incremental crawl

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-search

Environmental Setup: We've configured full crawl weekly once and incremental crawl 3 times daily. We have a library, which has > 3000 files.

Issue: Whenever a user search(Library Search) for a particular name(for example: full name), search results are showing older records which crawled last time and not displaying the latest search results. When the user searches with a particular name(for example: last name), search results are showing the latest results.

Scenario:
 1. When user searches "Ólafur Viktor" - it gives latest results
 2. When user searches "Ólafur" - it gives older results
 3. When user searches "Viktor" - it gives latest results

When I re-index this library, search works fine but after some days the issue again comes up and the same above scenario persists.

Please let me know how to fix this error related to Search indexing.
Thanks

Comment: What sort is your search results web part set to?

Comment: It is a normal document library with document sets and above mentioned names are document set name. No Sorting/filtering is applied.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint? Are you using Major and Minor Versions?

Comment: Using SharePoint 2013. If Major version is a concern then the above scenario 3 will also return old results right ? BTW publishing feature not enabled here.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott Thanks for your reply. May I know how to proceed to fix this error?

Comment: I don't know. It sounds like you don't have the crawler permissions set up correctly. Are you crawling content with an Admin account?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott I'm using dedicated crawl account which has admin privileges.

Comment: That is likely related to your issue. Your account should not have admin rights. It should only have read rights otherwise many things you do not want to show in search results will begin to show.